# Better way to create a pandas dataframe with variable feature length for regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, data-preprocessing

I am doing a project trying to see whether we can infer the power factor (cos(phi) = P/S) from voltage (U) and current (I) data. What this means exactly is not very important for my question. My question is about reshaping the data for regression purposes.

I have a dataset containing the columns: substation, installation, field, timestamp (5 min / timestamp), active power (P), reactive power (Q), current (I), and voltage (U). These are measurements across many different substations, where installations and fields are components within said substations.

For example the following dataframe (using Pandas in python 3.9) contains the all of the field measurements of substation 7, installation 0, timestamp 1000.

[image]

Since I am trying to solve this as a regression problem I want to form timeseries data where all of the fields in one substation installation are features connected to one timestamp.

My current main hurdle is how to reshape this in to useful timeseries data. Currently I use the following shape:

`[timestamp, substation, installation, P1, Q1, I1, U1, P2, Q2, I2, U2, ...]`

Where P1 is the value P for the first row, and P2 the value for the second row, and so on.
This system would work, albeit contain a huge amount of columns, if every substation and installation would have the same amount of fields. This is however not the case and every substation and installation is quite different. Ranging from sometimes 2 to 17 or more fields per installation. I made the dataframe such that the amount of columns would represent the largest possible amount of fields. Any smaller installation would have the first few columns filled with the representing data, but the rest is filled with 0's.

Since I want to use this timeseries dataset to train regression models I was wondering whether there was a better way to represent the variable size of substation installations?

Perhaps as some sort of list representation. Something along the lines of:

`[timestamp, substation, installation, Ps, Qs, Is, Us]`

Where `Ps = [P1,P2,..., Pn]` and can be variable length.

So in short: Is there a better way to represent this data as timeseries data for regression other than simply filling parts of the dataframe with 0's for non-existent fields?